# postgresql: How to sort a postgresql table in a permanent way?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am a having a table with columns `id`, `name`, and `date_time`. I need to sort the table according to the `date_time` column.

Actual data in database:

```
 id |   name         |         date_time
----+----------------+----------------------------
  1 | The flat       | 2022-07-06 09:17:07.990454
  2 | The Smetha     | 2022-08-08 09:17:07.990454
  3 | Kingston       | 2022-07-02 04:17:08.990454
  4 | The Oxford U   | 2022-08-08 04:14:08.990454
  5 | Studio Element | 2022-08-08 01:14:08.990454
  6 | The Davils     | 2022-08-02 04:14:08.990454
  7 | Latitude       | 2022-09-08 04:14:08.990454
  8 | Star Eight     | 2022-08-08 06:14:08.990454
  9 | Cottages one   | 2022-07-08 05:14:08.990454
```

I want to sort the `date_time` column in `ASC` order. Can I use the `RANK()` function?

Ex:

```
 id |   name         |         date_time
----+----------------+----------------------------
  1 | Kingston       | 2022-07-02 04:17:08.990454
  2 | The flat       | 2022-07-06 09:17:07.990454
  3 | Cottages one   | 2022-07-08 05:14:08.990454
  4 | The Davils     | 2022-08-02 04:14:08.990454
  5 | Studio Element | 2022-08-08 01:14:08.990454
  6 | The Oxford U   | 2022-08-08 04:14:08.990454
  7 | Star Eight     | 2022-08-08 06:14:08.990454
  8 | The Smetha     | 2022-08-08 09:17:07.990454
  9 | Latitude       | 2022-09-08 04:14:08.990454
```

Comment: Why do you have different IDs for the same name in two tables? Isn't it a primary key?

Comment: A table in a relational database has no implied sort order. The **only** (really: the _only_) way to get a guaranteed sort order, is to use an `order by` when selecting from the table. There is no alternative. You can make the sorting faster (e.g. by providing an index), but the **only** way to get a _guaranteed_ sort order is to use an `order by`

Comment: By design data stored within RDBMS is unordered (afaik in all databases). In Postgres specifically every DML operation will change the order stored. Basically the **only** way to ensure the order of a result set is using `order by` clause on the select statement.

Comment: Create a VIEW that is using an order that you like, and use this view instead of the table.

Comment: Relational database tables do not have inherent ordering. The qustion does not make sense as asked. Voting to close.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to sort the date_time column in ASC order. But here we should not use [...]  ORDER BY

That's like saying "I want so get the sum of A and B, but we should not use A+B"

`ORDER BY` is *the* way to sort tables in SQL. Tables in relational databases (as explained in comments) are not excel sheets, they are a set of records, and they lack an implicit order.

Answer (score 0):

Like others have said that the way to be sure that it will sort in a specific order is by specifying `order by column`, but in your case I did find something that does `order by date_time` without saying explicitly, **but it's not guaranteed**, and you need to add a new column, so if you ***really*** need to sort it ***without*** using `order by` this can be a *work around*.

```sql
select row_number() over(partition by date_time), id, name, date_time
from table
```

See [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=5491dc8749d877cfb046686dc186963d).

The reason why this would work is because it looks on each date and time in `date_time` column, and returns you groups of each date_time, so it really sorts it per date_time. So if you *need* to do the sort ***without*** using `order by`, you can use `row_number()`. But the **real** way to sort is by using `order by`.

Comment: Seriously? One of the worst answers I've ever seen in SO.

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz You're right but if the OP ***really*** want's **not** to use `order by` this is one way. That's what I say with *But the **real** way to sort is by using `order by`.* I don't know why he/she should do it, but maybe it's for a exam or something.

Comment: **(1)** The OP is obviously new to SQL. Guiding him in the wrong direction is not a kind thing to do. **(2)** You remind me of the classic Oracle practice where ORDER BY was skipped if the query already had a GROUP BY. Why? because the results were already sorted, and people though that a shorter syntax is cooler. ... and then one day Oracle introduced the hash-group algorithm and suddenly the results were not ordered any more. Getting the rows ordered in a specific scenario is not a proof and defiantly not guaranteed, not even for this specific example.

Comment: That is exactly what I say here *Like others have said that the way to be sure that it will sort in a specific order is by specifying `order by column`*

Comment: And yet you gave an answer, based on code that cannot be trusted, including a fiddle that cannot be trusted. Do the right thing and delete this answer.

Comment: I added the words *but it's not guaranteed*, is it still not good? It is a work around for now, if the OP needs it.

Comment: Let me clarify a few things why I think this answer should remain. The question says *I want to sort the date_time column in ASC order. But here we should not use order by*, this looks like HW especially *here we should not use*, also the OP knows about `order by` because the question asks **not** to use it. Now, is it the best thing? Absolutely **no**. But is there a way to do it? Yes. Is it guaranteed? No. But I think that looking on the question, this is the right answer, you may disagree, and I appreciate your comments.